# Concatinate strings in a dataframe column, based on grouping in another column

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe in this shape, which is holdling mostly textual data.  I've looked at transposition examples on stack overflow and they seem to be concerned with numerical values, rather than textual data.

```
Date         Route    Narrative
12/1/2020    A        ABC
12/1/2020    A        DEF
12/1/2020    A        GHI
12/1/2020    B        UVW
12/1/2020    B        XYZ
12/1/2020    E        ABC
12/1/2020    A        GHIE
12/1/2020    A        HUY
```

What I need is this data transposed by the Route column:

```
Date        Route     Narrative
12/1/2020   A         ABC DEF GHI
12/1/2020   B         UVW XYZ
12/1/2020   E         ABC
12/1/2020   A         GHIE HUY
```

I'm not asking for the codez, but rather what technique I should look at.  Pivot, melt, stack and unstack are all swimming around in my head...  I was thinking of iterrows to concatinate a temporary narrative for each row which is appended as a new column to the dataframe, but that seems like a lot of overhead.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `df.groupby(['Date','Route'])['Narrative'].agg(' '.join)`

Comment: Unfortunately this groups just by the "Route" column.  In the example above, the two instances of "A" need to be kept on seperate rows...

Comment: To identify blocks of identical routes, using `blocks = df['Route'].ne(df['Route'].shift()).cumsum()` and replace `'Route'` with `blocks` in `groupby`.

Comment: My apologies this does actually do what is needed.  I made a stupid error in testing